# jQuery appended items to a form are not posted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending some dynamic content to a form select using jQuery. When one of the appended options are selected and the form is submitted, the value is not being posted (this case in an email template). If I add another option into the code (not appended) this posts fine, so the issue is definitely with the appended data.

The code for the appended options is:

```
            var careersList = [
                {"CarId": "Name 1", "CarName": "Name 1"},{"CarId": "Name 2", "CarName": "Name 2"},{"CarId": "Name 3", "CarName": "Name 3"}
            ];
    for (var iCAR = 0; iCAR <= careersList.length; iCAR++) {
            $('#formsubjectselect_careers').append('<option value="' + careersList[iCAR].CarId + '">' + careersList[iCAR].CarName + '</option>');
        }
    var residentialList = [
                {"ResId": "Name 1", "ResName": "Name 1"},{"ResId": "Name 2", "CarName": "Name 2"},{"ResId": "Name 3", "ResName": "Name 3"}
            ];
    for (var iR = 0; iR <= residentialList.length; iR++) {
            $('#formsubjectselect_residential').append('<option value="' + residentialList[iR].ResId + '">' + residentialList[iR].ResName + '</option>');
        }
    var commercialList = [
                {"ComId": "Name 1", "ComName": "Name 1"},{"ComId": "Name 2", "ComName": "Name 2"},{"ComId": "Name 3", "ComName": "Name 3"}
            ];
    for (var iC = 0; iC <= commercialList.length; iC++) {
            $('#formsubjectselect_commercial').append('<option value="' + commercialList[iC].ComId + '">' + commercialList[iC].ComName + '</option>');
        }
```

The code for the selects is:

```
  <div class="row clearfix subjectselect_careers">
     <label for="formsubjectselect_careers">Career:</label>
    <select name="formsubjectselect_careers" id="formsubjectselect_careers"><option value="" selected>Please select...</option></select></div>

  <div class="row clearfix subjectselect_residential">
     <label for="formsubjectselect_residential">Property:</label>
    <select name="formsubjectselect_residential" id="formsubjectselect_residential"><option value="" selected>Please select...</option></select></div>

  <div class="row clearfix subjectselect_commercial">
     <label for="formsubjectselect_commercial">Property:</label>
    <select name="formsubjectselect_commercial" id="formsubjectselect_commercial"><option value="" selected>Please select...</option></select></div>
```

Comment: How are you POSTing your fields?  Do the elements get appended correctly, if you inspect the elements with devtools?

Comment: Can you give more details? like how is your data not being POSTed? is it just sending empty data instead of it? or aren't the events working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well as expected but you have some JS beginner errors. When fixed it works like a charm. 'for' loops in the manner you want to use have to be compared with '< xxx.lenth', but not with  '<= xxx.lenth' as you will get an undefined index of the array and this will generate an JS error, which will bypass all the rest of your block code.
Some extra incorrect code was present too. Please put a well formatted code next time - this will even help you to see more clearly your mistakes. Check the browser console for the errors, they will be reported there. I've put an submit handler which will log your form data in console, you have to remove it as it is just to show the form data submitted.

```js
$(function() {
  var careersList = [
    {"CarId": "Name 1", "CarName": "Name 1"},
    {"CarId": "Name 2", "CarName": "Name 2"},
    {"CarId": "Name 3", "CarName": "Name 3"}
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < careersList.length; i++) {
    $('#formsubjectselect_careers').append('<option value="' + careersList[i].CarId + '">' + careersList[i].CarName + '</option>');
  };
  var residentialList = [
    {"ResId": "Name 1", "ResName": "Name 1"},
    {"ResId": "Name 2", "ResName": "Name 2"},
    {"ResId": "Name 3", "ResName": "Name 3"}
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < residentialList.length; i++) {
    $('#formsubjectselect_residential').append('<option value="' + residentialList[i].ResId + '">' + residentialList[i].ResName + '</option>');
  }
  var commercialList = [
    {"ComId": "Name 1", "ComName": "Name 1"},
    {"ComId": "Name 2", "ComName": "Name 2"},
    {"ComId": "Name 3", "ComName": "Name 3"}
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < commercialList.length; i++) {
    $('#formsubjectselect_commercial').append('<option value="' + commercialList[i].ComId + '">' + commercialList[i].ComName + '</option>');
  };
  
  $('form').submit(function(){
     var formData = new FormData(this);
     for (var p of formData) {
       console.log(p);     
     } 
     return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

<div class="row clearfix subjectselect_careers">
  <label for="formsubjectselect_careers">Career:</label>
  <select name="formsubjectselect_careers" id="formsubjectselect_careers">
    <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix subjectselect_residential">
  <label for="formsubjectselect_residential">Property:</label>
  <select name="formsubjectselect_residential" id="formsubjectselect_residential">
    <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
  </select>
</div>

  <div class="row clearfix subjectselect_commercial">
     <label for="formsubjectselect_commercial">Property:</label>
    <select name="formsubjectselect_commercial" id="formsubjectselect_commercial"><option value="" selected>Please select...</option></select></div>
<input type="submit">
<form>
```

Comment: Of course the code could be re-written in more elegant way but I just tried to follow your idea.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use Ajax if you want to use Jquery for this. Or you can use modern Front End framework like Vue.js React.js etc. without jquery.

Comment: Why? It is quite possible to use JS to add elements to a form and post them without AJAX, Vue, or React.  If you don't think so, you need to explain why.

Comment: If you use Vanilla.js or jquery for changing a value,  the page must be refreshed by automatically or manually. If you use vue.js react.js or Ajax, it doesn't need to be refreshed.

Comment: Sure.  Did OP say they need that?

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that "if you want to change without refresh the page"

Comment: The page shouldn't be refreshed at all. You have a DOM!

Comment: This answer is full of false premises